# Why was the recent question about "unwarranted" suspensions deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, account-suspension

This isn't a big deal; I'm partially curious about what happened, but I also think it was a pretty good question with some very useful answers.

There was a question posted here yesterday by someone who was suspended on Stack Overflow for making rude comments on a question they'd asked. The person who was suspended did refer to that question, but also asked in a more general sense if there are improper or unwarranted suspensions.

(I don't have 10k here, so I can't see it or post a link for those who do, and I'm not sure it's appropriate to call out the person who posted it, although I could add that if comments ask for it.)

It's been over 12 hours since I last glanced at the question, but not a full day. When I last looked, there were 5 answers, some of which had relevant comments.

It looks like the question is gone now (not in the list of questions and not in the person's profile any more), which I think is a shame. I thought it was a perfect example of a user protesting their innocence ("Why was I suspended? I didn't say anything rude."), but very quickly some deleted comments were posted where the person was, in fact, rude.

It also turned out this wasn't their first suspension, and among the answers were a couple good explanations of how, when someone's been suspended a couple of times already, moderators are less likely to go to the trouble of explaining exactly what's wrong this time - when there's a pattern of rude comments, subsequent incidents are likely to trigger a suspension without explaining to the person again that rude comments aren't tolerated.

The final thing that I thought made it a good Q&A was that it was all fairly mild. The rude comments were clearly rude, but they weren't full of profanity, I don't think they'd bother anyone they weren't directed at.  And while the OP may have been protesting their innocence a bit much, they weren't raving about the unfairness of this latest incident. (Unless there was something posted after I last saw it.)

So my actual question about that question is: what happened to it? I assume since it had upvoted answers the OP couldn't delete it. If a moderator or a few regular users voted to delete it, is there any chance of un-deleting it, since (IMO) it's a pretty good Q&A?

Comment: Yeah, [this is the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303621/are-there-cases-of-suspensions-being-unwarranted) for those with 10k rep. It was deleted by Community Team member animuson 3 hours ago, probably because it's a known "troll", who keeps bringing such things up and cause uproar for no good reason. I remember more than a few times that user brought up such things, trying to bring attention to suspension, making accusations, and all in all trying to make people not trust SE staff and moderators. I support deleting such disruptive questions, even if they got answers.

Comment: Thanks for that link...  I know he often trolls, I've seen it a bunch of times on ScienceFiction&Fantasy.SE.  But on this question, even if he really must've known what he did wrong, I thought the total effect of the Q and the answers was useful.

Answer (score 10):

Let's not try to make things seem prettier than they actually are here. The question itself was a complete waste of time for everyone who was involved there. The only downside to its deletion is that it *wasn't deleted sooner* to prevent the amount of time wasted.

We do not support users who come to Meta pretending to be an innocent victim and intentionally withholding many facts about their situation in an attempt to sway users in one direction. Such questions are subject to immediate destruction. All they do is provide traps for users, and the information provided there does not actually serve to benefit any future users. As Journeyman has also said, all it was doing was providing a soapbox and airing a user's dirty laundry.

Comment: "that it wasn't deleted sooner to prevent the amount of time wasted" - so maybe prevent it to be posted to begin with by suspending users who keeps doing it? I can't see that user's deleted questions, but pretty sure he already did it before right here in MSE, maybe more than once.

Comment: On the other hand, its the only recourse they have, and even broken clocks are right twice a day - not in this case of course. I wouldn't feel that its right to delete (maybe close) it as a user either.

Answer (score 7):

It's actually a pretty regular occurrence - and I fully admit to posting answers expecting to lose that reputation, depending on when it got deleted, simply cause I figure its for the greater good of the community (granted, balanced between that and feeding the troll.)

It's not really a constructive post and *historically* these things never end well. Looking at the question - well, OP has said some rather ill considered, and impolite things in some answer comments.

Post was deleted since posts of that nature *invariably* devolve into bickering, namecalling, "but moooooom"s and so on and past a certain, short lifespan, serve no real purpose other than as a soapbox, and maybe a reversal badge mine.

We probably should just close and delete rather than answer but....

[image]

<sub>[link to original page.](https://xkcd.com/386/)</sub>

So yeah, it was deleted cause it was about one site, an attempt to get sympathy or a soapbox, and did no one any good.